# Broken HDD hard drive: How to format drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I was playing Rust and then everything that was using my secondary disk (D) crashed. It asked to format my disk but instead I decided to restart my pc. I restarted it and my drive wasn't recognised and then the next day, I was getting spammed messages to format the drive, I decided to go to computer and I saw the drive was appearing and disappearing. I couldn't format it either because my pc won't recognise it for long enough. The file type was changed to RAW too.

Comment: You don't;  It sounds like you experience a HDD failure;  You should replace the HDD.

Comment: so there's nothing i can do to fix it? (excluding going to a pc repair place)

Comment: *I was getting spammed messages*. You were actually getting unwanted email messages asking you to format your disk?

Comment: Your HDD is malfunctioning.  Even if you were to format the drive, our advice, would be to replace the drive.  You shouldn't waste your money taking it to somebody, they won't be able to do anything you can't do, even if they do format the drive you should replace the drive.  *The drive in question should not be used.*

Comment: "so there's nothing i can do to fix it? (excluding going to a pc repair place)"  Based on the information provided here? Nope.

Comment: ken white they were windows messages and thanks for the quick answers guys

Comment: Was the disk showed in BIOS setup? What does Windows disk manager show? Where are the RAW files placed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities of what happened:

1. the disk itself(the shiny plate inside the HDD) was damaged.
2. the controller of the HDD was damaged(the pcb in the back of it)
3. the sata cable is damaged(probably not if its reappearing)

how to fix:

1. replace your HDD
2. order a new controller(or buy an exactly same HDD and switch controllers)
3. replace your sata cable and reformat disk